# What's the minimum number of datapoints in order to run a diff-in-diff?

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, difference-in-difference

I was thinking about running a diff-in-diff with fixed effect in order to deal with a panel data experiment. The problem is that I don't know how many datapoints I need in order to the experiment be reliable.

This is the thing: I want to see how my customers react to a change in price. An AB test doesn't look like a good alternative, due to [cannibalization](https://blog.wiser.com/what-is-product-cannibalization/). So I would like to change the price of a bundle of products in some cities. Let's say for cities A, B, C and D, cleaning products will be 10% cheaper. Then I would run a diff-in-diff with fixed effects using each city datapoint. The question is: how many cities do I need in order to run this experiment? How many sales each city would have to have in order to the experiment be reliable?

Comment: You might consider using synthetic cohort method for this.

Answer (score 0):

DID estimation uses four data points to deduce the impact of shock on the treated population: the effect of the treatment on the treated.

OTOH, the required number of sample points does depend on objects. If you are doing exploratory analysis just to see if one model (say linear in a covariate) looks better than another (say a quadratic function of the covariate) less than 10 points may be enough. But if you want very accurate estimates of the correlation and regression coefficients for the covariates you could need more than 10 per covariate.